Where do I upload video demo of background geolocation?
My app recently got removed from Google Play because they couldn't view the video I'd attached showing the use of background geolocation. This happened because the video in Google Drive got removed. I've re-added it to Google Drive, but don't know where to add the link to it in the Google Play console. Where should I add this, along with notes I want to provide giving extra info on my use of background geolocation?
Here is the documentation I'm following describing what video to attach. I just couldn't find where/how to attach it.

This is off-topic, as it's specific to an App Store, and not a programming question - see Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?
